# Strange Nginx behavior with trailing slashes

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config

I've got a quite interesting behavior. I want to avoid trailing slashes in URL's on my site. I've put `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;` rule into my server block, so 
`https://example.com/something/`,
`https://example.com/something////`
redirect to 
`https://example.com/something`;
and 
`https://example.com/` 
redirects to 
`https://example.com`

But `https://example.com////` is redirected to ... `https://enjoygifts.ru////` (actually don't redirected, it's 200 code). Why?

Here is my server block:

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ...
        ... ssl directives
        ...

        root        /var/www/mysite.com;
        index       index.php;
        server_name mysite.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

        location / {
            rewrite ^/.*$ /index.php last;
        }

        location ~ ^/index.php {
            try_files    $uri =404;
            include      /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ ^/storage/app/uploads/public { try_files $uri 404; }
        ...
        ... lot of similar location blocks
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https://example.com` doesn't really exist, the root URI is `/` - how it's displayed in the browser's address bar is browser dependent - some will automatically show the solitary `/` whereas others will remove a solitary `/`.

So you cannot redirect from `https://example.com/` to `https://example.com` - it will be silently interpreted as a redirect from `https://example.com/` to `https://example.com/`.

Nginx uses a [normalized URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) when evaluating `location` and `rewrite` statements, and generating the `$uri` variable. Multiple consecutive occurrences of `/` are folded into a single `/`.

Although the regular expression `^/(.*)/$` matches the URI `//`, the statement will never see it. Because Nginx has already normalised that URI to `/`, which does not match the regular expression.

---

If a root URI with multiple `/`s is a problem, apply a regular expression to the `$request_uri` variable, which contains the original URI before normalization and also includes the query string (if any).

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ "^/{2,}(\?|$)") { 
    return 301 /$is_args$args; 
}
```

This can be placed inside your `location / {...}` block. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. 
Ok, due to Nginx normalization and `^/(.*)/$` regex we can get `/something` from `/something////` (`/something////` -> `/something/` -> `/something`). But if `^/(.*)/$` can't see `////`, how can it possible to erase `////` from browser's address bar?