# How to get rest of this NGINX 203 error from PHP-FPM

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I keep getting a 203 error from NGINX and could use some help resolving it.
I get this error when I go to http://localhost, http://localhost/index ... etc.
The site works perfectly fine.

```
[error] 60#60: *203 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message:" while reading response header from upstream, client: ::1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"
2019/10/25 13:34:35 [error] 60#60: *203 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message:" while reading response header from upstream, client: ::1, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
```

Conf:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /mnt/c/Users/me/src/site;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


        server_name _;


location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                # Make sure unix socket path matches PHP-FPM configured path above
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

                # Prevent ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING when browser hangs on response
                fastcgi_buffering off;
        }

}
```

I'm assuming it might have something to do with this:
[Strange Nginx behavior with trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53168398/strange-nginx-behavior-with-trailing-slashes). But I don't fully understand.

Comment: Try adding this below server_name: `error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;`, restart nginx, and see if that error log give you more information.

Comment: Added and restarted NGINX, no change. However, I am noticing my routes aren't working. There must be something off in the config...

Comment: That line won't make it start working, but it should hopefully write better error messages to that error log. Check the log to see if it gives any more information.

Comment: The error is actually from PHP, emitted over stderr and relayed to Nginx by php-fpm. You could try configuring PHP to write errors to its own error log file rather than writing them to stderr. Check the `php.ini` file and directives such as `log_errors` and `error_log`.

Comment: log_errors is on. error_log is set to the default file. I do see php errors (like from code) in the php log.

Comment: Another strange I noticed. Now, if I go to localhost, it downloads the php file. But if I go to localhost/login, it loads the default (not login) controller. Argh!

Comment: NM the last comment, it was a browser cache issue.

Comment: I had a few small things wrong. But the accepted answer answered the question I actually asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HTTP Proxy sits in the middle between a client and a server (origin). In some cases a HTTP Proxy might make changes to the response before it reaches the client.

So, you are realy shure what you are get 203 error come from YOUR nginx-server?